# Discord oauth2 unsupported_grant_type

Tags: c#, asp.net, discord

I'm trying to get a discord token using the code, but I keep getting a "None grant type is not supported"

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using(HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(
          HttpMethod.Post, "htt://discord.com/api/oauth2/token")) {
  var data = new {
      client_id = ulong.Parse(_config["client_id"]),
      client_secret = _config["client_secret"],
      grant_type = "authorization_code",
      code = confirmcode,
      redirect_uri = "https://localhost:7258/api/auth",
      scope = "messages.read",
  };
  req.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8,
                                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var result = await _client.SendAsync(req);
  result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Grant type None is not supported"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was that you need to send not a jsonbody, but a Form Url Encoded, I attach a working version

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using(HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(
          HttpMethod.Post, "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token")) {
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
      {"client_id", _config["client_id"]},
      {"client_secret", _config["client_secret"]},
      {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
      {"code", confirmcode},
      {"redirect_uri", "https://localhost:7258/api/auth"},
      {"scope", "messages.read"}};
  req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
  var result = await _client.SendAsync(req);
  result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var json = JsonNode.Parse(response);
}
```